# Dry skin, Breathing problems, dry lips, dry sinuses when low carb diet

Tags: diet, breathing, ketogenic-diet, low-carb, skin

I have been diagnosed with diabetes type 2 and low carb works to get my levels back in order.

However whenever I go low carb, I feel completely dried out... dry lips, dry skin, breathing problems, dry sinus, blood shot eyes, headaches etc...

Is this an electrolyte issue ? Am I consuming too much sodium without getting the others or is there something else at play blood pressure ?

Edit: Also tonight what felt like flatulence turned out to be something far messier.. and afterwards have been feeling very weak, heavy headed... something feels off.

Typical meal.

Frozen meat ( steak, sausage etc..)
Frozen Broccoli and spinach.
Couple of eggs
Garlic Mayo.

Then not long after I find it hard to breath and completely dried out... also begin to hold a lot of water despite drinking plenty of water through the day.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I too am diabetic and, strangely, those are typical symptoms of high blood sugar.

Comment: Any idea what might be going on ? last week fed up with feeling crap, I went off track and was eating utter rubbish... mcds, mcflurrys etc but felt very good... this week since returning to low carb as I know this is what I should be eating for my T2 and  all those symptoms have cropped back up.

Also had an accident earlier... fart that wasn't a fart and since have been feeling extremely heavy headed and sweating.

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't like to speculate because I'm no doctor. All I know i those symptoms, specifically the dryness, are exactly what I experience during episodes of high blood sugar. All I can recommend is consulting an actual doctor